# How to use like with [] values in data in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * 
from Table1 
where Email = 'test()<>[]:;@\\@test.com' 


select * 
from Table1 
where Email like '%test()<>[]:;@\\@test.com%'
```

The first query is returning data, while the second query is not. How can we use `like` in this query?

The second query should return the same data as the first.

Comment: [] is part of the LIKE pattern matching. which matches empty set of characters. To be able to use such characters, you have to ESCAPE them with a escape clause. Read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Why do you want to use `LIKE` when `=` is returning the expected result? The LIKE predicate and the equals to operator are not interchangeable, they do different comparisons-

Comment: What are you trying to do? This string isn't a valid email address nor can it be used to match email addresses

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, sometimes it's better not to know :P

Comment: Quite the opposite, the `why` is 120% of the answer. Especially in this case which makes little sense on its own

Answer (score 2):

As @siggemannen has rightly pointed out :
(I will use his original sentence from above comment):

[] is part of the [LIKE pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). which matches empty set of characters. To be able to use such characters, you have to ESCAPE them with a escape clause.

So,
Your query can be written as :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Email LIKE '%test()<>\[\]:;@\\\\@test.com%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Here is a [demo using dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HAAvvzd-)